# AWS Athena with DynamoDB data source and Glue crawler has case-insensitive columns

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I deployed AWS Athena DynamoDB connector into my account and created Glue Crawler for DynamoDB table.

The problem is that schema in Glue is case-insensitive and when I use that table in Athena via DynamoDB connector then my projection in columns has no value.

I suspect this is caused by case-insensitive column names (all in lowercase). I have both tables with Glue and without Glue metadata and those that are detected with Athena Connector without Glue support work (column names are case-sensitive and in correct format).

Is there any way to configure Glue with DynamoDB to honour case-sensitivity? I even tried to manually alter column names in Glue but everything is lower-cases upon save.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a table property 'columnMapping' on the table created by the crawler to map the lowercase names to the actual Dynamo column names.

For example: `columnMapping: id=ID,userid=UserId,...`

This will let you query correctly the table using the lowercase columns created by the crawler.